# If $abcd=1$,where $a,b,c,d$ are positive reals,then find the minimum value of $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd$.

Tags: inequality

If $abcd=1$,where $a,b,c,d$ are positive reals,then find the minimum value of $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd$.

---

Let $E=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd=(a+b+c+d)^2-(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)$
I do not know how to use $abcd=1$ in this question to get the minimum value of the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Use the AM-GM inequality, which establishes $$\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}{n} \ge \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\dots a_n}$$

When $a_1,a_2, \dots, a_n$ are positive reals.

For example, $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \ge 4\sqrt[4]{a^2b^2c^2d^2}=4$

Answer (score 0):

with AM-GM, we get
a²+b²+c²+d² ≥ 4√((abcd)²) = 4
ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd ≥ 6√((abcd)³) = 6
minimum value of a²+b²+c²+d²+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd is 4+6 = 10 when a=b=c=d=1.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).